# Pandas importing DataFrame Vs whole library - Speed and memory concern

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a helper function that use pandas DataFrame multiple times, but I don't need any other pandas functions.

Is it better to import the whole library and call DataFrame to make the code more consistent or just import DataFrame?

My function will be called over 100,000 times and return a dictionary.

```py
import pandas as pd
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

VS.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
temp_df = DataFrame()
```

Comment: An import statement _always_ loads the entire package in memory. However, the syntax of the import determines what namespaces are made available to you in your program (in the first case it is `pd` meaning your can access everything inside the package, in the second it is only `DataFrame`).

Comment: Thanks, @cs95. I'm aware of this effect. my question is about the memory usage and speed in comparison of loading the whole package vs loading only one needed function. Is there any overload or python do a lazy load as an example.

Comment: Like I said before, any import statement will load the entire package, whether you're able to access the whole package or not. I'm pretty sure there are some submodules that are not imported unless you specify a direct import yourself (you'll see this a lot with sklearn and nltk for example) but you can't selectively import classes and functions, no.